# How to copy a file without copyFile

Tags: node.js

How can I copy a file synchronously without using `fs.copyFile` function? (I am using an older version of Node.js which does not have `fs.copyFile`)

Comment: Please specify the exact version of nodejs (`node -v`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it synchronously you can use [writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) / [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('test-copy.txt', fs.readFileSync('test.txt'));
```

Else use [createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) / [createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('test.txt').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test-copy.txt'));
```

Comment: Is this synchronous operation?

Comment: `createReadStream` / `createWriteStream` is not synchronous. Use `writeFileSync` / `readFileSync` if you need to perform this operation synchronously